# How to implement an image in a JsonSerializable model class

Tags: json, image, flutter, dart, model

I need to be able to retrieve and also to store an image using an API. For my model classes I'm using @JsonSerializable.

What I'm struggling with is the data type to use for the image in my model. From the API I get a base64 encoded string, the image_picker plugin gives me a File.

What's the best way to implement this in my model? I could imagine to use a String (base64 encoded) as this is what I get from the API. It should also not be to hard to get the base64 representation from the File I get from image_picker.

Would be great to also have the fromJson and toJson functions for the solution as I had issues with those implementing some of my ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize/deserialize the model objects by doing something as below.

```
class Doughnut {
 final String name;
 final String filling;
 final String topping;
 final double price;

 Doughnut(this.name, this.filling, this.topping, this.price);

 Doughnut.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
     : name = json['name'],
       filling = json['filling'],
       topping = json['topping'],
       price = json['price'];

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
   'name' : name,
   'filling' : filling,
   'topping' : topping,
   'price' : price
 };
}
```

You can refer to this [source](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47) for serializing and deserializing your model objects.

As far as the Image serialization is concerned, you should go with the base64 string approach. it will be easy to serialize an image this way along with other data.

Edit:
 if the serialization in base64 string is not preferred, then what you can do is store the image to device storage and just store the path of the image when serializing, but in this you'll have to do two processes:

1. Get storage permission for the app
2. Check for file when deserializing, You'll need to handle resulting scenario as per your requirements.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is currently my opinion as well. But I have two concerns: keeping the base64 data in my model is a bit of a memory waste as I need the bitmap representation for the GUI at the same time and also, base64 is probably not the most efficient way to store an image. For lots of images this could become a problem.